# ReSharper running all tests using Machine Specifications

Tags: unit-testing, resharper, mspec

I'm trying to debug a specific MSPEC test, but it seems ReSharper is running all the tests. My session only contains the one test, but breakpoints get triggered and I can clearly see in the stacktrace they're from another test.

After running, the session still displays just the single test I'm trying to run. I also noticed this when not debugging, for example when running a specific test which would get delayed because of other longer running tests.

Using R# Ultimate 2016.2.2 and Machine.Specifications.Runner.Resharper 1.6.0-beta5. I tried different variations, starting a fresh session by adding the test, using Run Test, using Debug Test and still the same behavior - while the session window only shows the one test after running, it's clearly running more than just the one I want.

Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Are talking about different assertions (i.e., `It` delegates), or really different specs (i.e., classes with single `Because`)?

Comment: I can clearly see in call stack they're from another Specs that aren´t in the session that it´s running.

Comment: You better create an issue for that right here: https://github.com/machine/machine.specifications.runner.resharper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed,

My BaseSpec now have a Establish and not a simple constructor, now I can debug test by test, not all